# Graph Isomorphism with Same Degree Sequece

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-isomorphism

How do I prove that two tree graphs with the same degree sequence are isomorphic (or non isomorphic)?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false.  See [this paper](http://webbox.lafayette.edu/~gordong/pubs/oldtree.pdf) for examples.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It really helped me out! :)